# extract limited number of tweets in python

Tags: python, request, tweepy

```
import tweepy

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

from tweepy import OAuthHandler

from tweepy import Stream

import json



access_token = ""

access_token_secret = ""

consumer_key = ""

consumer_secret = ""



class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):       

        try:

            with open('anusri.json', 'a') as f:

                f.write(data)

                return True

         except BaseException as e:

                print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
         return True

    def on_error(self, status):

        print (status)

if __name__ == '__main__':


    l = StdOutListener()

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    places = api.geo_search(query="IND", granularity="country")

    place_id = places[0].id

    tweets = api.search(q="place:%s" % place_id)

for tweet in tweets: 

    stream.filter(track=['modi'])
```

**How do i limit tweets to 100**

Comment: According to http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.search, the number of `SearchObject`s returned can be no more than 100; in particular, limiting the number to 100 should happen automatically.

Comment: I mean not 100 in particular but some number of tweets @fuglede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set the 'return per page' to 100:

```
tweets = api.search(q="place:%s" % place_id, rpp=100)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, you might consider adding an explanation to make it a good answer.

Comment: Can i get tweets more than 100?

Comment: I don't think so since the documentation states that `search` has a limit of 100. But you can supply `page=2`, `page=3`, and so on to collect up to 1500 results.

Comment: How can i add that page=2 or 3 in my code?                                       tweets = api.search(q="place:%s" % place_id, page=2)                                                   This gave me an error